# Ruby VM concurrency and parallelism

Tags: ruby, concurrency, parallel-processing, scalability, multiprocessing

I have a general question about the Ruby VM (Ruby Interpreter ). How does it work with multiprocessors? Regarding parallelism and concurrency in Ruby, let's say that I have 4 processors. Will the VM automatically assign the tasks with the processors through the Kernel? With scaling, lets say that my ruby process is taking a lot of the CPU resources; what will happen if I add a new processor? Is the OS responsible for assigning the tasks to the processors, or will each VM work on one processor? What would be the best way to scale my ruby application? I tried as much as possible to separate my processes and use amqp queuing. Any other ideas?

It would be great if you can send me links for more explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ruby Threading

The Ruby language itself supports parallel execution through a threading model; however, the implementation dictates if additional hardware resources get used.  The "gold standard" interpreter (MRI Ruby) uses a "green threading" model in 1.8; threading is done within the interpreter and only uses a single system thread for execution.  However, others (such as JRuby) leverage the Java VM to create actual system level threads for execution.  MRI Ruby 1.9 adds additional threading capability but (afaik) it's still limited to only switching thread contexts when a thread stalls on an I/O event.

### Advanced Threading

Typically the OS manages assignment of threads to logical cores since most application software doesn't actually care.  In some high performance compute cases, the software will specifically request certain threads to execute on specific logical cores for architecture specific performance.  It's highly unlikely anything written in Ruby would fall into this category.

### Refactoring

Per application performance limits can usually be addressed by refactoring the code first.  Leveraging a language or other environment more suited to the specific problem is likely the best first step instead of immediately jumping to threading in the existing implementation.

#### Example

I once worked on a Ruby on Rails app with a massive hash mapping function step in it when data was uploaded.  The initial implementation was written completely in Ruby and took ~80s to complete.  Rewriting the code in ANSI C and leveraging more specific memory allocation, the execution time fell to under a second (without even using threads).  The next bottleneck was inserting the massive amount of data back into MySQL which eventually also moved out of the Ruby code and into threaded C code.  I specifically went this route since the MRI Ruby interpreter easily binds to C code.  The final result has Ruby preparing the environment for the C code, calling it as a Ruby instance method on a class with parameters, hash mapping by a single thread of C code, and finally finishes with an [OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org) worker queue model of generating and executing inserts into MySQL.

Comment: This was an impressively informative answer for being so brief, and it did an excellent job addressing the concerns of the question. +1

Comment: Thanks.  I should also note that moving the single threaded inserts from Ruby to C didn't actually gain performance initially.  It was only after I went to a multithreaded implementation that the code saw higher throughput.  It actually managed to saturate at 45K-rows/s regardless of the number of threads and length of extended inserts.

Comment: I'm sure that using C to do time consuming process is the best after al, but as for my current implementation 10 K rows/s is more than enough, if I got more requests then I will be rich and i will hire an expert :) for my solution i'm using async_query and threading the connections , something like     (threads ||=[]) << Thread.new{
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|{ #some stuff here } } and class Mysql; alias :query :async_query; end . something like that made inserting queries like 5X faster